# Prevent horizontal scrolling on the view of a Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scroll

I am creating a Listview dynamically with c# . As a result I don't have the listview in my xaml.

Is there a way of setting the horizontal scroll bar visibility = hidden?

I am looking for something like:

```
listView1.HorizonalScrollBarVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

or since the listView1.view = gridview1 then maybe I have to do somthing like:

```
gridview1.HorizonalScrollBarVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

---

**I have tried:**

[image]

also:

```
     listView.View.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden);

     gridView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden);
```

gives the same exeption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(listView1, ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden);